# (MySQL) I want to update another table and this table has trigger. and I get an error "because it is already used by statement"

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables.

DOG table

```
|-----------------------|
| ID | NAME | STATUS_ID |
|-----------------------|
| 1  | Tom  |  1        |
|-----------------------|
```

APPLICATION table

```
|---------------------------|
| ID | DOG_ID | IS_RETURNED |
|---------------------------|
| 1  | 1      |  0          |
|---------------------------|
```

AND I have a view table

```
select A.ID, B.ID DOG_ID, B.NAME, A.IS_RETURNED
FROM DOG A
INNER JOIN APPLICATION B
ON A.ID = B.DOG_ID
```

When I try to update IS_RETURNED to 1, (update view_table set IS_RETURNED = 1 where DOG_ID = 1) I get an error "Can't update table 'DOG' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger."

Triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER `AFTER_UPDATE_DOG` AFTER UPDATE ON `DOG`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.STATUS_ID <> OLD.STATUS_ID AND NEW.STATUS_ID = 2 THEN
    INSERT INTO APPLICATION (DOG_ID, PAYMENT_STATUS_ID, CREATED_DATE) VALUES (NEW.ID, 2, SYSDATE());

    END IF;

    IF NEW.STATUS_ID <> OLD.STATUS_ID AND NEW.STATUS_ID = 1 THEN
    INSERT INTO APPLICATION (DOG_ID, IS_FINALISED, CREATED_DATE) VALUES (NEW.ID, 1, SYSDATE());
    END IF;
END

CREATE TRIGGER `AFTER_INSERT_DOG` AFTER INSERT ON `DOG`
 FOR EACH ROW UPDATE DOG SET AGE = NEW.ID WHERE ID = NEW.ID

CREATE TRIGGER `AFTER_UPDATE_APPLICATION` AFTER UPDATE ON `APPLICATION`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF NEW.IS_RETURNED <> OLD.IS_RETURNED AND NEW.IS_RETURNED = 'Yes' THEN
        UPDATE DOG SET STATUS_ID = 3 WHERE ID = NEW.DOG_ID;
    END IF;
END
```

Which trigger cause error ? I try to solve problem. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which query are you running to *update IS_RETURNED to 1*, ie which query generates the error?

Comment: I have view which join DOG table and Application table.and "Update View_table set IS_RETURNED = 1 where DOG_ID = 1

Comment: What if you update the `Application` table directly, are you getting the same error? `UPDATE application SET IS_RETURNED = 1 where DOG_ID = 1`

Comment: No I don't get any error. but I need to update view table. I am creating table on WordPress and use wpDataTable plugin. I need to use view table so that global search works on wpDataTable (global searching does not work on join queries)

Comment: Did you try to just `UPDATE application ...` and then see if the changes reflect in the view? That might just work.